# Make a list of files in a directory (Batch)?

Tags: shell, batch-file, for-loop

I'm trying to make a list of items in the "C://Program Files" directory, but I'm new to Batch and I'm unsure of how I would do this. I'm more familiar with high-level languages like Java and scripting languages like Lua, but recently I've wanted to learn low(er)-level languages like Assembly and Batch (if you can actually count Batch as a language...).

How would I do this?

I've already changed the directory to the Program Files folder but I have no idea how to make a list of files (from my time in languages like Lua I know I'll need to use a For loop, but I'm unsure of how to do this).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `DIR` command `DIR /?`

```
Dir /b *.* >list.txt
```

Comment: `/a-d` for files only (without directories).

Comment: Is there any way to put them into an internal array rather than adding them to the list.txt file?

Answer (score 0):

Typing in Dir C:***\   (the rest of the path) will list all the items in that specific folder.